# How can I output a list of data frames in R to a csv file so that the data frames are listed vertically?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, csv, output

I have a list of data frames in R that I would like to output to a csv file, with the data frames listed vertically in the csv file. The output command that I tried is this:

write.csv(model_diagnostic_list,"Model diagnostics.csv")

However, the resulting csv file has the data frames all lined up horizontally, which doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0):

We can `rbind` the datasets in the `list` first and then write it to csv (assuming the datasets have the same column names)

```
write.csv(do.call(rbind, model_diagnostic_list), "Model_diagnostics.csv")
```

If some of the `list` elements have different columns, we can use `bind_rows` (from `dplyr`) or `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
bind_rows(model_diagnostic_list) %>%
     write_csv(file = "Model_diagnostics.csv")
```